# How many active ASP.NET developers are there?

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for metrics on how many ASP.NET developers are actively using ASP.NET.

If you have links to reliable metrics I would be interested to see them.

Comment: It's going to be impossible to get a true number. However, a good measure could be a survey of all hosting services and see the percentage that offer ASP.NET support. Even better, contact them directly.

Comment: @JAtkinson Surely there is a study that provides a round figure.

Comment: @Chris - the reason I added the 'subjective' and 'offtopic' tags to your post is because they are just that. This is not a 'programming' question per se, and would therefore be offtopic. And the number is subjective because you are not going to get an accurate number.

Comment: @JasonBunting Which is more subjective, your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428/what-considerations-should-be-made-before-reinventing-the-wheel or mine? Answer honestly. Yours could be an ongoing discussion. Mine there might actually be an accurate study.

Comment: @Chris: pointing out hypocrisy, even if accurate, is a bad habit - if your post is on-topic and has an objective answer, then make an argument for it; otherwise, accept that Jason was accurate in his tagging.

Comment: @Shog9 I did make an argument, you should read my previous response all of the way. There likely is an fairly accurate study out there that has evaluated the number of ASP.NET developers. I'm looking for that study.

Comment: That said, i don't find [subjective] useful as a tag - who would ever filter on it? An [offtopic] filter might be useful though, for folks just looking for idle entertainment. Even better would be a specific *sort* of OT - [demographics], similar to the existing [poll] and [gtky] tags.

Comment: @Chris: "surely there is a study that provides a round figure" ?! How is that an argument? If i were to write, "Surely there is a site dedicated solely to programming Q&A", that wouldn't make it true.

Comment: @Shog9 I stated that I'm looking for an accurate study, what's the issue with that?

Comment: Well, Jason's argument for subjective was that you won't *get* an accurate study. I don't care, since i don't think the subjective tag is useful (as i already stated). Anyway, I've re-tagged the question per my own flimsy guidelines now. ;-p

Comment: @Shog9 demographics is cool.  I thought you said you didn't like 'subjective'? Here you said you do like 'subjective'.

Comment: Eh? I've stated twice that i don't think it's useful.

Comment: Sorry, misread it. You're right.

Answer (score 2):

http://news.netcraft.com/

They have decent metrics on what server type sites are using.  You could go from there by saying that the windows ones *could* be running asp.net sites but even then you'd be guessing.